# Laravel usage of get and view in Route

Tags: laravel

When should I use get and when should I use view? How to decide clearly?

```
Route::view('/contact','contact',['name'=>'Superhuman'])->name('contact');

Route::get('/contact/{name}','ContactController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

> If your route only needs to return a view, you may use the
>   `Route::view` method. Like the `redirect` method, this method provides
>   a simple shortcut so that you do not have to define a full route or
>   controller. The `view` method accepts a URI as its first argument and
>   a view name as its second argument. In addition, you may provide an
>   array of data to pass to the view as an optional third argument:

For more information you can visit the official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#view-routes)

```
Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome');

Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome', ['name' => 'Laravel']);
```